# What did Sylvie mean by this line in the Loki (2021) finale?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

During the finale, Sylvie tells Loki:

> "I was pruned before you existed."

Did I miss something in an earlier episode, or was this a mistake on the part of the writers? I know she was "kidnapped" by the TVA, but don't remember seeing that happen to her

> prior to her self-pruning in episode 5.

Answer (score 22):

The technical meaning of pruning someone or something by the TVA would be resetting it, or in practice sending it to the Void. However, in context of the sentence it doesn't really matter. Sylvie is getting Loki to shut up so she can continue her life's mission, the exact terminology she uses here doesn't really matter. Her point is she was taken from her timeline, her *home*, and it was destroyed.

> **Sylvie:** Loki, shut up. I was pruned before you even existed. I have been waiting for this moment my entire life. I just need a second to get my head straight, okay?
>
> <sub>*Loki*, Season 1 Episode 6, "For All Time, Always"</sub>

On top of that, as [FuzzyBoots points out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/251503/58193) her timeline *was* pruned. They "reset" it when they take Sylvie away. So whilst she was not physically pruned herself her home was and the TVA would have pruned her if she didn't escape. Ever since then they have been trying to prune her, her whole life. So whilst she might not be technically correct in saying she was pruned for the purpose of the conversation and for the overall meaning as it applies to her it's pretty accurate and doesn't matter that much.

Comment: But does it matter??  I'm not sure because you said it doesn't three times in six sentences  :)

Answer (score 19):

While Sylvie herself was not pruned, it is shown that, after she was removed from her timeline, a [Reset Charge](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Reset_Charge) was left behind that erased it, which effectively removed her from the Sacred Timeline without an evident means to return, pruning her from the timeline even if

> She was not sent to [the Void](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Void).